# CRM 2015- The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I am getting this error for all plugins -

```
The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.
```

I have tried restarting the sandbox service.It has startup type as Automatic(Deplayed Start). I have also disabled the firewall. But its still giving me that error.

How do i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check what user that service is running as and confirm that their login is working.

I would also check the Windows Application Event Log.

Beyond that, you might want to enable [tracing](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/907490/how-to-enable-tracing-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm) while attempting to start the service.

Back in the day, the [CRMDiagTool](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=crmdiagtool2011) used to come in very handy for managing tracing.